# How to create sql server stored procedure with output parameter and call from C#

Tags: c#, parameters

Still i get an error **"The formal parameter "@result" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output"**.
here is my code in c#

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddRoomType", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeName", TxtType.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;              


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

my stored procedure in SQL server

```
Create proce AddRoomType
@TypeName nvarchar(50),
@result int

as
if(exists(select * from TblRoomTypes where RoomType = @TypeName))
set @result = 0
else 
begin
set @result = 1
insert into TblRoomTypes (RoomType) values (@TypeName)
end
```

please Help

Comment: i dont know what is wrong, i have declared my parameter as an out put but still get that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Your Parameter as `OUTPUT` when creating the Stored Procedure

```
create proc AddRoomType
    @TypeName nvarchar(50),
    @result int out          -- ** NOTE it's declared as 'OUT' ** 

as
  if(exists(select * from TblRoomTypes where RoomType = @TypeName))
    set @result = 0
  else 
  begin
    set @result = 1
    insert into TblRoomTypes (RoomType) values (@TypeName)
  end
```